# How to identify the flash on site

Tags: wordpress, flash

I've inherited a large Wordpress site and we still have some Flash on our site. 
Browsing on Firefox shows the insecure content icon and asks if I want to run an outdated version of flash so I know it's there.

How can I identify where the flash is from my browser side? Or is there a simple command on the server side to find it?

Comment: Do you mean to build a list of pages that contain Flash so you can replace that code or upgrade it? Do you have access to the command line? If so, you can use `grep` or `ack` to find Flash related code.

Comment: I have access to the command line. So something like `grep -r swf`?

Comment: Also to answer the first part of the question, yes! I'm looking for any pages that contain flash code so I can upgrade it.

Comment: Looks about right, if you're at the top of the directory tree. You can direct the STDOUT to a log file using `>swf_log.txt` at the end of that. Depending on how complex the code replacement is, you might be able to use `grep` to upgrade all of your source code in one shot (after backing it up) - see: [How to grep and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace)